# Is it necessary to take a general approach in demonstrating that the set $S$ is nonempty

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and let $b \in \mathbb{N}$. To prove the division algorithm, we defined the set $S$ by
$$S = \{a-kb \, | \, k \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } a-kb \geq 0\}$$
In order to use the well-ordering property, we first must demonstrate that $S \neq \emptyset$.

The texts I've read usually adopt a general approach in showing that $S$ is nonempty, like one book says that because $b\geq 1$we have
$$a - (-|a|)b = a+ |a|b \geq a + |a| \geq 0$$
Choosing $k = -|a|$, it follows that $a - kb \in S$.

However, my question is if this more abstract approach is necessary. Would it be sufficient to show that just one particular number belongs to the set, like $0$? Choosing $a = k = 0$, it follows that $a - kb \geq 0$, and thus $0 = a-kb \in S$.

Comment: You can't choose $a$

Comment: I think you might be confused on what $S$ is in this context: the variables $a$ and $b$ are fixed. Then $S$ is defined as the set of expressions $\{a-kb\}$ where only $k$ is allowed to vary. Otherwise said, $S$ is a function of $a$ and $b$ - we're trying to show that it's always non-empty, no matter what $a$ and $b$ were chosen as.

Comment: You can't choose the value of $a$, the number $a$ is given in advance. You could choose $k = 0$, so that $a - kb = a$, but we don't know that $a$ is nonnegative.

Comment: Ah, of course. Given integers $a$ and $b > 0$, we need to find a $k$ that forces $a-kb$ to be nonnegative, thereby showing that $S \neq \emptyset$. Makes sense!